# jQuery Ken Burns effect and Parallax on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I'm really pulling my hair out with this one. Hopefully I'm overlooking something obvious!

I've got a page that needs both a Ken Burns effect slider and a Parallax banner (overkill I know, but very specific design requirements!)

http://www.northliving.co.nz

I can get the KB and Parallax effects working separately however when I try and do them together I get weird, inconsistent rendering; i.e. very slightly different (but all incorrect) positioning of the parallax section - see below.

[image: Three Different Errors]

I've tried the following to no avail:

- Using jQuery's delay() to space the two effects out.
- Clearing local and server cache.
- Commenting out all other jQuery used
- Testing in the latest versions of Chrome, Safari and Firefox

Thanks - would really appreciate any ideas!

Comment: Update: very oddly it works perfectly if I have the developer tools window open! (Chrome, Safari or Firefox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase someone else is having a similar problem my solution was triggering a jQuery resize after a delay using:

```
function resizeBrowser() {
    $(window).trigger('resize');
}
setTimeout( resizeBrowser, 1500);
```